# (Regular Expressions) How to add Lookaround (Lookbehind) in to this expression

Tags: regex

I have written a regular expression but am confused on how to inject a lookaround into it.

I have the following strings:

```
myName is myLastName
yourName is yourLastName
```

and I want, using negative lookbehind, to make it only match the one which does not include myName. myName is not surely in the beginning of the sentence, it might just be in the middle of another longer phrase. Up to here, I have written the following match reg exp which match both of the sentences (naturally), but I want to add a condition using negative look behind:

```
(([a-zA-Z]*)( *)(is)( *)([a-zA-Z]*))
```

Comment: You don't have to use a regex for that; also, why the capturing groups for spaces and `is` anyway?

Comment: It will be better if you clarify what are you trying to match from above input.

Comment: Also, why are you tagging this with three languages? Regexes work differently in different languages (for example JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind at all).

Comment: I want to add a negative lookbehind. I'm a newbie and that's why you might see illogical things...I want to learn negative lookbehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use **negative lookbehind**, then following regex should work:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?<!\bmyName\b) +is +([a-zA-Z]+)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eY8oG3

`(?<!\bmyName\b)` is a negative lookbehind that doesn't match a word that is preceded by literal string `myName`. `\b` is for word boundary.

Comment: Note, this won't work in Javascript (it's unclear what the author is using though)

Comment: Yes true JS doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to *match* the string which doesn't contain the word `myName`, then you can use the following regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!myName).*$/
```

**Explanation:**

- `/` - starting delimiter

  - `^` - assert position at the beginning of the string
  - `(?!` - negative lookahead
  - `myName` - matches the characters `myName` literally
  - `)` - end of lookahead
  - `.*` - match any character (except newline) zero or more times
  - `$` -  assert position at end of the string
- `/` - ending delimiter

Essentially, the above regex will match any string that doesn't contain the word `myName` (case-sensitive).

**Test case:**

```
$arr =['myName is myLastName','yourName is yourLastName'];

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('/^(?!myName).*$/', $str, $matches)) {
        echo 'Match', PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'No match', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
No match
Match
```